# PHP Form - BCC not receiving emails

Tags: php, forms, formmail

I'm trying to BCC an email in my PHP form. For some reason, the following code isn't sending the form to the BCC address:

```
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($from) . "\r\n" . "BCC:test@test.com";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($from) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Apart from the BCC not receiving the email, the form works. For the BCC part, I used the accepted answer at:
[Add BCC field to a php contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078798/add-bcc-field-to-a-php-contact-form)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your BCC is not delimited by `\r\n` and so the reply-to header is joined to the BCC value (making it invalid).

The mail server is seeing the BCC header as:

```
BCC:test@test.comReply-to: xxx@example.com
```

Change to:

```
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($from) . "\r\n" . "BCC:test@test.com\r\n";
```

---

Side note: `strip_tags()` is not enough to protect against a header injection attack. You must validate the from email address properly.

Comment: Thanks MRCode - the BCC field now works. Can you point me to any tutorials on email address validation?

Comment: PHP5 has built in email validation using `filter_var`. See http://uk3.php.net/filter_var